# Puppeteer not able to get page's innerHTML using evaluate

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the HTML from a site but puppeteer can't get the HTML. Same code works for multiple other sites I'm downloading.

What makes this website different and disallows evaluate function from getting the content?

Even jQuery is unable to access the the elements on this site. The file downloaded does seem to have an iframe but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const fs = require('fs');
const nodepath = require('path')
var url = 'http://example.com';

var oddsOutputPath = nodepath.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'outputdir');

console.log(oddsOutputPath);
fse.ensureDir(oddsOutputPath).then(() => { console.log('success!') }).catch(err => { console.error(err) });

function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    networkIdleTimeout: 0,
    timeout: 360000,
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox'
    ]
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', request => {
    if (['image', /* 'stylesheet', */ 'font'].indexOf(request.resourceType()) !== -1) {
      request.abort();
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
  });

  try {
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 653 });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 360000 });
    await delay(45000);

    outputPath = oddsOutputPath + "/init.html";
    let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, html);


    console.log('script has ended');
    await delay(5000);


  } catch (e) {
    var error = "'" + e + "'";
    console.log(error)
    process.exit()
  }
  finally {
    await browser.close();
  }


})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are trying to access loads the majority of its content in an iframe.

I would recommend accessing the iframe directly to scrape its content:

```
var url = 'https://elitebet-sportsbook-web.exaloc.net/prelive_event/?token=&language=en';
```